# How to add daily ema25 to indicator across every timeframe

Tags: pine-script, moving-average, indicator

I am trying to update my personal indicator to include the daily ema25 for every time frame(1H/4H etc) and I have been unable to correctly plot the ema.

can anyone identify what is wrong with the code below? or advise how I can add the daily ema25?

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Primary Trading", shorttitle="Primary", overlay=true)

//ema 13
ema13Source = input(defval = close)
ema13Length = input.int(defval = 13, minval = 1)

//ema 25
ema25Source = input(defval = close)
ema25Length = input.int(defval = 25, minval=1)

// ema 30
ema30Source = input(defval = close)
ema30Length = input.int(defval = 30, minval = 1)

// ema200 - actually SMMA99
ema200Source = input(defval = close)
ema200Length = input.int(defval = 99, minval=1)



//Declare EMA
ema13 = ta.ema(ema13Source, ema13Length)
ema25 = ta.ema(ema25Source, ema25Length)
ema30 = ta.ema(ema30Source, ema30Length)

EMA200() => 
    ema200 = 0.0
    ema200 := na(ema200[1]) ? ta.sma(ema200Source, ema200Length) : (ema200[1] * 
(ema200Length - 1) + ema200Source) / ema200Length

EMA25() =>
    ema25 = 0.0
    ema25 := na(ema25[1]) ? ta.sma(ema25Source, ema25Length) : (ema25[1] * 
(ema25Length - 1) + ema25Source) / ema25Length

h4ema200 = 0.0
h4ema200 := request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"240", EMA200())

h1ema200 = 0.0
h1ema200 := request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"60", EMA200())

d1ema25 = 0.0
d1ema25 := request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", EMA25())

//Draw lines
plot(series=ema13, title="EMA13", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, 
style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(series=ema25, title="EMA25", color=color.white, linewidth=1, 
style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(series=ema30, title="EMA30", color=color.red, linewidth=1, 
style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(series=h4ema200, title="4hEMA200", color=color.red, linewidth=1, 
style=plot.style_cross)
plot(series=h1ema200, title="1hEMA200", color=color.gray, linewidth=1, 
style=plot.style_cross)
plot(series=d1ema25, title="1dEMA25", color=color.green, linewidth=1, 
style=plot.style_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you recalculating the emas yourself instead of using the built-in ta.ema() function?